# How do I group results in columns using case statements?

Tags: sql-server, sum, case-when

I want to group the results in a separate column as `Idle Total`, `Lock Total` etc. I'm not a programmer and certainly not an db admin so i may not have all tools and access but I'll appreciate any help.

I've tried using other methods, here and other websites but it always comes down to the `SUM` or `GROUP BY` functions which I understand very little of.

```
SELECT TOP 10000
    AGENT.AGENT_NAME,
    ID.AGENT_ID,
    TIME.DURATION_SECONDS,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN ID.AGENT_ID IN ('IDLE','LOCK','LOGIN') 
              THEN 'WORKSTATE' 
           ELSE NULL 
        END)
FROM 
    WORKSTATE TIME
LEFT JOIN 
    DATABASE ID ON ID.INDEX = TIME.AGENT_INDEX
LEFT JOIN 
    DATABASE ORG ON TIME.AGENT_LOGIN_ID = ORG.AGENT_NAME
WHERE 
    (TIME.START_TIME = 2019-08-19) AND ORG.TEAM IN 'COMPANY'
GROUP BY 
    AGENT_AGENT_NAME,
    ID.AGENT_ID,
    TIME.DURATION_SECONDS
```

I would like the results to group TOTAL time an agent was Idle, Locked or Login on a given date.

```
Date Name Idle hrs Lock hrs Login
---  ---  ------    ------  -----
08/19 John   2.3      1.7     4
```

Comment: You would need four columns in your select statement to get four columns in your output. No idea what column you are trying to create a sum for though. You have a string literal which will blow up because summing a string doesn't work.

Comment: The sample data to go with that expected result will greatly help us.

Comment: This looks like an opportunity to use SQL Server's PIVOT operation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: There are multiple issues here. First, the value _2019-08-19_ is a math expression - so that won't work. Next, you cannot sum a string - which is what your case expression returns. Use of TOP without an order by clause will return an undefined set of rows. You have a column whose name includes "seconds" yet your desired output implies hours. Obviously there is some math to convert between units. So start with a basic query that selects rows for a particular person and date. Then build on that step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `CASE` expression for each column, following query would help you to start with:

```
SELECT 
    TIME.START_TIME,
    TIME.AGENT_LOGIN_ID,
    SUM(CASE 
           WHEN ID.AGENT_ID = 'IDLE'
              THEN TIME.DURATION_SECONDS  END) as IdleTime, -- You may calculate You can formula to get HOURS from SECONDS or replace the column "DURATION_SECONDS" with the one that you looking to do aggregation
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ID.AGENT_ID = 'LOCK'
            THEN TIME.DURATION_SECONDS  END) as LockTime, 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ID.AGENT_ID = 'LOGIN'
            THEN TIME.DURATION_SECONDS  END) as LogTime
FROM WORKSTATE TIME
LEFT JOIN 
    DATABASE ID ON TIME.AGENT_INDEX = ID.INDEX
LEFT JOIN 
    DATABASE ORG ON TIME.AGENT_LOGIN_ID = ORG.AGENT_NAME
WHERE 
    (TIME.START_TIME = 2019-08-19) AND ORG.TEAM = 'COMPANY'
GROUP BY 
     TIME.START_TIME, TIME.AGENT_LOGIN_ID,
```